# broken LXC on Debian

Tags: debian, lxc

I have a Debian machine where I wanted to run an Ubuntu LXC container.
I successfully followed [this guide](https://www.unixmen.com/setup-linux-containers-using-lxc-on-ubuntu-15-04/), but ended up without network.

Then I tried to follow [this](https://wiki.debian.org/LXC#Networking_Essentials), but I think I broke something on my LXC installation.
Here's the steps I executed:

Added these lines to `/etc/lxc/default.conf`

```
lxc.net.0.type = veth
lxc.net.0.link = virbr0
lxc.net.0.flags = up
# you can leave these lines as they were:
lxc.apparmor.profile = generated
lxc.apparmor.allow_nesting = 1
```

Then:

```
$ $ sudo apt-get install -y libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system iptables ebtables dnsmasq-base libxml2-utils iproute2
$ sudo virsh net-start default
$ sudo virsh net-autostart default
```

After that, whenever I try to start my container, I get the following:

```
$ sudo lxc-start -n ubuntu01 -d
lxc-start: ubuntu01: lxccontainer.c: wait_on_daemonized_start: 842 Received container state "STOPPING" instead of "RUNNING"
lxc-start: ubuntu01: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 330 The container failed to start
lxc-start: ubuntu01: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 333 To get more details, run the container in foreground mode
lxc-start: ubuntu01: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 336 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options
```

What did I do wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Debian 11 bullseye(the current stable), you should use `$ lxc-unpriv-start -n ubuntu01`